# TypeError: must be str, not int Python3 issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

What's wrong with the line6:

```
 name = (input('Hi, please enter your name '))
dob = int(input('Hi please enter your DOB '))
today = int(input("Hi please enter today's date "))
future = int(today + 5)
diff = str(future - dob)
print ('Hi ' + name + 'in the year of ' + future + 'you will turn ' + diff)
```

I keep getting error:

```
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

How do you guys debug in general? I'm new to programming. Is there a way to know exactly where it wants string?

Comment: You should be able to see the line number where the error occurred in the traceback. In general, you can debug by removing things until the error disappears, then put the last thing you removed back (in which you will find the error).

Answer (score 2):

Python can't automatically convert integer variable to string.

You need to explicitly convert `future` variable to `str` type like this:

```
print ('Hi ' + name + 'in the year of ' + str(future) + 'you will turn ' + diff)
```

Answer (score 1):

`future` is an **integer**, therefore, it cannot be concatenated with a string. You can do this:

```
print ('Hi ' + name + 'in the year of ', future, 'you will turn ' + diff)
```

OR cast `int` to `str`

```
print ('Hi ' + name + 'in the year of ' + str(future) + 'you will turn ' + diff)
```

Example:

```
name = (input('Hi, please enter your name '))
dob = int(input('Hi please enter your DOB '))
today = int(input("Hi please enter today's date "))
future = int(today + 5)
diff = str(future - dob)
print ('Hi ' + name + 'in the year of ', future, 'you will turn ' + diff)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Documents>py test.py
Hi, please enter your name job
Hi please enter your DOB 1876
Hi please enter today's date 2018
Hi jobin the year of  2023 you will turn 147
```

Example:

```
name = (input('Hi, please enter your name '))
dob = int(input('Hi please enter your DOB '))
today = int(input("Hi please enter today's date "))
future = int(today + 5)
diff = str(future - dob)
print ('Hi ' + name + 'in the year of ' + str(future) + 'you will turn ' + diff)
```

Output:

```
Hi, please enter your name job
Hi please enter your DOB 1876
Hi please enter today's date 2018
Hi jobin the year of 2023you will turn 147
```

Comment: your solution doesn't seem to work:

Comment: Why? It is working

Comment: Look both are perfectly working @Galapagos.

Comment: the original suggested:

future = str(int(today + 5))
print ('Hi ' + name + 'in the year of ' + future + 'you will turn ' + diff)


so inserting into the code:


name = (input('Hi, please enter your name '))
dob = int(input('Hi please enter your DOB '))
today = int(input("Hi please enter today's date "))
future = str(int(today + 5))
diff = str(future - dob)
print ('Hi ' + name + 'in the year of ' + future + 'you will turn ' + diff) 



does not work .

Comment: I know what is your point?